# Query returns nothing when using startAt/endAt

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Trying to get angularFire to work with startAt and endAt limits.
I have uploaded data setting the priority price like this:

```
[
  {
    "value": [
      {
        "id": "188278",
        "name": "DOUGLAS",
        "city": "Douglas",
        "beds": "0",
        "baths": "1",
        "price": "7950"
      }
    ],
    ".priority": "7950"
  },
  { ...etc.
```

On Firebase it looks like this:
[image]
If I make a call with angularFire like this I get data back:

```
$scope.updatePriceList = function(from, to){
    var url = new Firebase('https://manxmove.firebaseio.com/price/975');
    var data = angularFireCollection(url)
    $scope.properties = data;
};
```

However, if I change the URL to:

```
var url = new Firebase('https://manxmove.firebaseio.com/price/').startAt(from).endAt(to);
```

and pass 500,1000 to the function, I get nothing back.

I have tried several ways of setting the priority without success. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT...
Just to add a bit more detail, here are a couple of screenshots of the debugger. This time I'm not using angularFire. The first one shows the data I get back without any limits:

[image]

If I add startAt(500), I would expect a subset of the data starting at 500. The first value (275) should be dropped. However, I get no results at all:

[image]

EDIT 2: 
Here's the php code that produces the json shown at the top:

```
        $url = 'https://manxmove.firebaseio.com/';

        $fb = new fireBase($url, $token);
        $price_path = "/price/";

        $prlist = [];
        foreach($plist as $pp){
            $d = array('value'=>$pp,'.priority'=>$pp[0]['p']);
            array_push($prlist,$d);
        }

        $response = $fb->set($price_path, $plist);
```

Comment: How are you setting your priorities? It seems like they are not being set correctly, the following code only reports "null": `ref.once("value", function(snap) { snap.forEach(function(s) {console.log(s.getPriority();}); });`

Comment: Here's a snippet of the json I send to firebase: [{"value":[{"id":"188278","n":"DOUGLAS","c":"Douglas","d":"0","b":"1","p":"7950"}],".priority":"7950"}, ....

Comment: Are you sending this data via REST? If you're using the JavaScript API to populate the data, I'd recommend using setWithPriority instead as it seems the priority isn't reaching the servers.

Comment: I am writing the data with php REST and reading it with javascript

Comment: it seems like your priorities aren't being written correctly; I'd double check your REST code to make sure they're making it to the server.

Comment: Thanks! I've just added the php that I use to write to the DB. I'm using the Firebase PHP Client Library by Tamas Kalman